# Post always got http error 500 : ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult accountchange(int id, int accountid, bool activate)
    {
        // Operations
        return Json(new { Model = model, Result = true, Message = "Changed Successfully });
    }

    $('#accountchange-button').click(function () {
        alert("");
        $.post("url/accountchange/", {id:1, accountid:1, activate:1},
            function (data) { $('.result').html(data); }, "json");

    });
```

always got:

```
POST http://localhost/account/accountchange/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
                f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.min.js:4
                f.extend.ajaxjquery.min.js:4
                f.each.f.(anonymous function)jquery.min.js:4
                (anonymous function)demo:105
                f.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3
                f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

any idea?

Comment: You should be to see the full the XMLHttpRequest's response within Chrome developer tools or Firebug. The response from your server will have more information than just an HTTP status code.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error - what do your server error logs say?

Comment: thanks jaredhoyt, i will debug with firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I don't see model being defined. That's my best guess as to why your application is returning a 500 application error. As previously mentioned in the comment, you can use the inspect element utility to figure out what the server is actually complaining about.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult accountchange(int id, int accountid, bool activate)
{
    // Model = model is most likely undefined
    return Json(new { Model = model, Result = true, Message = "Changed Successfully });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your routing in Global.asax to accept the 3 parameters you are passing?

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{accountId}/{activate}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, accountId = UrlParameter.Optional, activate = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

Comment: i dont use model MattSavage in this action